# Why did question 2487921 get reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

We have two almost exactly the same questions in PHP that deal with converting date format from one to another:

[Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)
[Convert a date format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php) <- reopened

For a long time, they were marked as duplicates, but someone decided to reopen it. I would like to ask for a broader opinion about these questions. Should they be closed as duplicates or do we really need two identical questions.

Comment: The first seems to also include time of day ;)

Comment: @Scratte Which would suggest that it's a better question.

Comment: You have a PHP gold-hammer :) I think you can safely use it here :) Maybe give it an hour and see if anyone agrees with me.

Comment: I've pinged the user who reopened, but I don't entirely understand why you feel the need to ask "why" when it was reopened in 2018 by a hammer. The title doesn't match with what you're asking here, though, which isn't why it was reopened, but if they should be closed as duplicates again.

Comment: @Zoe I don't want to get into close-reopen war in case there is a good reason I am not seeing. I can close it again, but if it was closed incorrectly in the first place then I would like to know why it was reopened and whether it is acceptable to close it again

Comment: @Zeo out of curiosity, where did you ping them? In a chat? I can't see any comments under the post...

Comment: @Yatin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008503/css-styling-every-nth-column-in-a-table/67008627#comment118803233_67008627

Comment: It was like 2½ years ago and I don't remember what I was thinking. Perhaps I wanted to swap the duplicates but forgot; the one that was opened has more views and more upvotes as of now; may be that was the case back then.

Comment: @SalmanA Ok, but the one with less views is better in my opinion and it will continue to receive less views if we don't link to it.

Comment: I closed them again seeing as nobody has any obvious objections, but I leave this meta open in case someone else decides to voice their opinion on this closure.

Answer (score 20):

> *"Why did question 2487921 get reopened?"*

Because someone with a gold badge in [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) didn't think the duplicate closure was appropriate, **3 years ago**.

We don't need to discuss every single closure on Meta. Just cast your vote if you disagree with the current status.

Comment: And we have gold badges in a date tag. Let that sink in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get a `date` gold badge before a gold badge in one or more language tags, tho... The user that re-opened them has quite the collection.

Comment: Only on php and arrays, apparently lost the date badge :)

Comment: You're looking at the wrong user ;-)

Comment: Oh no... what we've done...